# Array inside object | database insertion

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, mongodb, object

I have the following array of objects. Currently it have one object containing several inside of it.

```
let arr = 
    [
     {
        "data": {
            "Score": {
                "score": [
                    "87",
                    "21"
                ],
                "Player": [
                    "Wiki",
                    "Tim"
                ]
            },
            "Designation": {
                "By": [
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "1",
                    "0",
                    "0"
                ],
                "Position": [
                    "31/07/17",
                    "31/07/17",
                    "31/07/17",
                    "31/07/17",
                    "31/07/17"
                ]
            },
            "Address": {
                "Location": "London",
                "House_No": "43-B",
            }
        }
    }
]
```

The above data will go in one table.

I have tried looping it and inserting but did't got any way out. The above data is not constant means will change like `Position` have 5 elements, It can be 6 next time, So i cannot simply insert it via its indexes.

I have tried things but no success.

Comment: SQL tables cannot store data like that.  Learn about foreign keys.

Comment: Depends on database type and database structure. Not enough known

Comment: @Slaks i am using parse server, It is on Mongo.

Comment: Then what's the problem?

Comment: @Charlietfl Database is parse, And the one table will store the above data.

Comment: @Slaks How should i insert the above data, I cannot simply insert one by one i have to insert all available data in one row possibly. I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql can store json data, and you can parse after you fetch, even you can parse json data from mysql queries but thats little complex if data changes, so its better to store it, fetch and parse.
You can select feild type JSON and store json in it.

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `tags` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

you can insert json data in it by using php function:-

```
$json_data = json_encode($json_data);
```

insertion command will be:-

```
INSERT INTO `book` (`title`, `tags`)
VALUES (
  'ECMAScript 2015: A SitePoint Anthology',
  '$json_data'
);
```

For manipulating json data via mysql queries there are several function like JSON_ARRAY(), JSON_OBJECT() and so on, which you can prefer to use. Please refer to below article for details:-
https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/

Comment: But OP said they are using mongo on parse server

Comment: @charlietfl is right, I am using Mongo DB. And i don't have to store the json. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: @Jimmy but mongo is for storing json. I think you need to study some tutorials on structuring mongo or noSql databases in general. It's already very evident you don't understand how they work

Comment: You can directly store json in mogodb

Comment: Check my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Mongodb if you have dynamic data you can use mixed type schema like below:-

```
details:Schema.Types.Mixed,
```

Sample schema:-

```
// grab the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');
// create a schema
var casesSchema = new Schema({
    sku: {type:String, unique:true},
    details:Schema.Types.Mixed,
    created_at: {type:Date, default: Date.now},
    images: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    ebay_hosted_images: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    cloudinary_hosted_images: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    dropbox_hosted_images: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    is_listed:Boolean,
    user_id : {type: String, ref:'User'}
});
casesSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
var cases = mongoose.model('cases', casesSchema);

module.exports = cases;
```

Answer (score -1):

In **ES6** you can simply get all keys and value of an object like this:
`Object.keys(myObj).forEach(key => {
    console.log(key);          // the name of the current key.
    console.log(myObj[key]);   // the value of the current key.
});`
If it is an array for each use to get the all values
`arr.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element);
});`
`arr.push(element)`  is used to push the element to as last index of array.